# If $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix. I want to show that if $e^\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I know the converse is true, but I'm not sure how to go the other way. Our assumption seems to be equating power series to each other, which seem more difficult to work with.

Thanks!

Comment: It is true only for real $\lambda$ (otherwise, there are counterexamples starting from $\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ and $\Bbb C^{1\times 1}$).

Comment: What you can say is that if $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$, then $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $e^{\lambda} = \mu$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this is the question, right?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif it is not the question.  For instance:
$$
\exp \pmatrix{0 & -2 \pi\\ 2 \pi & 0} = I
$$
$e^1$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$, but $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You mean $e^0$, right?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval yes.  $e^0$ is an eigenvalue of $e^A$, but $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

As Omnomnomnom says, you can only prove that $\lambda+2i\pi k$ is an eigenvalue for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. This follows immediately from the following useful fact:

Let $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_k$ denote the (complex!) eigenvalues of a matrix $A$. Then the (complex!) eigenvalues of $e^A$ are $e^{\lambda_1},\ldots,e^{\lambda_k}$. (This can be proved using Jordan's theorem).